# Putting the last integer on a new line when outputting integers in ascending order

Tags: c++

In the code below, I am trying to output the integers in ascending order.  It works, however I want the final integer to be put on a newline (final integer only- not the other integers).  I have tried

```
cout << myVec[i] << " "; endl
```

and...

```
cout << myVec[i] << endl;
```

but, both do not give the output I am looking for (these affect the other integers which is not what I want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void SortVector(vector<int>& myVec)
{
  int n = myVec.size();
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n - i - 1; j++)
      if (myVec[j] > myVec[j + 1])
      {
        int temp = myVec[j];
        myVec[j] = myVec[j + 1];
        myVec[j + 1] = temp;
      }
}

int main()
{
  int i, n, value;
  cin >> n;
  vector<int> myVec;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    cin >> value;
    myVec.push_back(value);
  }
  SortVector(myVec);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cout << myVec[i] << " ";
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In which way did it fail?

Comment: Reading the shown code is not fun, please remove most of the empty lines. Also have a look at formatting https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help and learn about and apply some consistent indentation scheme.

Comment: Sorry about that- I will definitely apply that to my future posts!  The code is not failing, however I need the final integer to be printed on a new line.  I am having a hard time isolating the final integer only.

Comment: @KingCharlesCavaliers2 Did you notice my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Print all but the last element on one line:

```
for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) // notice n-1
    std::cout << myVec[i] << ' ';
std::cout << '\n';
```

Then you can print the last afterwards:

```
if(myVec.size())
    std::cout << myVec.back() << '\n';
```